# Android - Build block of views dynamically and append it to Layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I have a block of `Views` containing an `ImageView`, a `Button` and a `TextView`. I want to create this block dynamically in the `Java` code. Is there a way to define this block in XML, alter the `src`/`text` attributes and append it to my current `layout`?

Thanks!

Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following technique:

```
<!-- content.xml -->
<merge>
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/image />
  <Button android:id="@+id/button />
  <TextView android:id="@+id/text />
</merge>
```

Then inflate using a [`LayoutInflater`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html):

```
View block = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content, root, attach);
(TextView) textView = (TextView) block.findViewById(R.id.text);
textView.setText(text);
```

I found this especially useful when you write a custom `View` extending a `ViewGroup` (eg `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`) and you want to define the content in a declarative XML. For example

```
public class MyWidget extends LinearLayout {

  // Invoked by all of the constructors
  private void setup() {
    Context ctx = getContext();
    inflate(ctx, R.layout.content, this);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(
        ctx.getString(R.string.hello_world)
    );
  }
}
```

A possible variation is using a `Layout` instead of `<merge>` if you don't need it. The `LayoutInflater` can be obtained by [`Activity.getLayoutInflater()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLayoutInflater%28%29) or by any `Context` via [`getSystemService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29) (you have to cast the result to a `LayoutInflater` object in the latter case.

Comment: if i use this block several times...how do i avoid having trouble addressing the views via id? the id/image will be there several times, wont it?

Comment: The `id` is just an identifier to find views. It doesn't even need to be unique inside a hierarchy. Nothing happens when two views have the same ID. The only problem is that when you invoke `View.findViewById(int)` and two or more views with the same ID exist, because in this case you may not find what you were looking for (you may want to use `setTag(Object)` in some circumstances). However with my code you won't have any problem, because the inflater returns the last created hierarchy, and you can call `findViewById` on this hierarchy, and in `content.xml` the aren't duplicate ID

Comment: hm...it seems that only one block is appended... any ideas why?